# How to use third party library classes like apache in installa4j Scripts

Tags: install4j

I want to use third party library classes (e.g. org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils) inside  installa4j script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the JAR file of the dependency one the "Installer->Custom code & resources step", then you can use the contained classes in scripts.

You can either use fully-qualified class names or write import statements at the top of the script.